# Grafos: maior caminho

Tags: java, algoritmo, programação-dinâmica

Bom, como trabalho da faculdade, tenho que criar um algoritmo que, dado certo arquivo com *x* números, seja capaz de verificar qual a maior sequência de números que, em base 6, respeitem as as seguintes regras:

1. A sequência deve ser crescente
2. De um número para outro da sequência, somente um dígito pode mudar
3. Todos os números da sequência tem que ter o mesmo número de digitos (15-->10015 não é válido)

Um exemplo seria:

> O arquivo contém os números 782, 229, 446, 527, 874, 19, 829, 70, 830, 992, 430 e 649.
>
> Ou seja, em base 6: 3342, 1021, 2022, 2235, 4014, 31, 3501, 154, 3502, 4332, 1554 e 3001.
>
> Portanto, a maior sequência respeitando essas regras seria: 649, 829 e 830, que corresponde a 3001, 3501 e 3502 em base 6.

Certo, os arquivos não são assim tão simples, há arquivos que chegam a ter até 100.000 números, portanto, criei um grafo. Eu tentei tanto com matriz como com lista de adjacências. Adicionar os vértices e as arestas (ou seja, quais são os números que respeitam as regras para um número *x*) não foi um problema, meu problema é caminhar no grafo, pois pesquisando na internet só achei caminhamento mínimo, mas o que eu preciso é: achar o maior caminho.

Tentei com DFS mas o resultado não é o que eu quero.

Meu código é o seguinte:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class DirectedGraphList
{
    private class Vertice
    {
        private String item;
        private boolean Visitado;
        private ArrayList<Vertice> lst = new ArrayList<Vertice>();

        public Vertice(String item) {
            this.item = item;
        }
        public String getItem() {
            return this.item;
        }
        public void setItem(String item) {
            this.item = item;
        }
        public void addAdjacent(Vertice v) {
            if (!lst.contains(v))
                lst.add(v);
        }
        public ArrayList<Vertice> getAdjacents() {
            return lst;
        }
        public Vertice getAdjacent(int i) {
            Vertice res = null;
            if ((i >= 0) && (i < lst.size()))
                res = lst.get(i);
            return res;
        }
        public int getDegree(){
            return lst.size(); 
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<Vertice> vert;

    public DirectedGraphList() {
        vert = new ArrayList<Vertice>();
    }

    private Vertice searchVerticeRef(String item)
    {
        Vertice res = null;
        int i;

        for (i = 0; ((i < vert.size()) && !vert.get(i).getItem().equals(item)); i++);

        if (i < vert.size())
            res = vert.get(i);

        return res;
    }

    public void addVertice(String item)
    {
        if (searchVerticeRef(item) == null) 
        {
            Vertice novo = new Vertice(item);
            vert.add(novo);
        }
    }

    public void addEdge(String strOrig, String strDest)
    {
        Vertice vAux1 = searchVerticeRef(strOrig);
        Vertice vAux2 = searchVerticeRef(strDest);

        if (vAux1 == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Aresta origem invalida: " + strOrig);
        else if (vAux2 == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Aresta destino invalida: " + strDest);
        else
        {
            vAux1.addAdjacent(vAux2);
        }
    }

    public int getNumVertices() {
        return vert.size();
    }

    public int getDegree(String vertice)
    {
        int i, j, c = 0;
        Vertice v = searchVerticeRef(vertice);
        if (v != null)
        {
            // grau de saida
            c += v.getDegree();

            // grau de entrada
            for (i = 0; i < vert.size(); i++)
            {
                if (!vert.get(i).getItem().equals(vertice))
                {
                    for (j = 0; j < vert.get(i).getDegree(); j++)
                    {
                        if (vert.get(i).getAdjacent(j).getItem().equals(vertice))
                            c++;
                    }                    
                }
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAllAdjacents(String vertice)
    {
        ArrayList<String> res = null;
        Vertice v = searchVerticeRef(vertice);
        if (v != null)
        {
            res = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int j = 0; j < v.getDegree(); j++)
                res.add(v.getAdjacent(j).getItem());
        }
        return res;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getSources()
    {
        ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
        boolean checked;
        String vertice;

        for (int k=0; k<vert.size(); k++)
        {
            vertice = vert.get(k).getItem();

            checked = false;
            for (int i=0; i<vert.size(); i++)
            {
                for (int j=0; j<vert.get(i).getDegree(); j++)
                {
                    if (vert.get(i).getAdjacent(j).getItem().equals(vertice))
                    {
                        checked = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!checked)
                res.add(vertice);
        }
        return res;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getSinks()
    {
        ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i=0; i<vert.size(); i++)
        {
            if (vert.get(i).getAdjacents().isEmpty())
                res.add(vert.get(i).getItem());
        }
        return res;
    }

    public void showInfo()
    {
        System.out.print("V = { ");
        for (int i = 0; i < vert.size()-1; i++)
            System.out.printf("%s, ", vert.get(i).getItem());
        System.out.printf("%s }\n", vert.get(vert.size()-1).getItem());

        ArrayList<String> arestas = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < vert.size(); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < vert.get(i).lst.size(); j++)
                arestas.add(String.format("(%s, %s)", vert.get(i).getItem(), vert.get(i).getAdjacent(j).getItem()));

        System.out.print("E = {\n");
        if (!arestas.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.printf("      %s", arestas.get(0));

            for (int i = 1; i < arestas.size(); i++)
                System.out.printf(",\n      %s", arestas.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("\n    }");
    }
    public static void criaArray(ArrayList<Integer> a,String nome) throws FileNotFoundException{
        try{
            FileReader ler= new FileReader(nome);
            BufferedReader arq=new BufferedReader(ler);
            int parsedStr;
            String str=arq.readLine();
            while(str!=null){
                parsedStr=Integer.parseInt(str);
                a.add(parsedStr);
                str=arq.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Erro na abertura do arquivo: "+
                    e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static int diferente(String a,String b){
        int diferentes=0;
        if(a.length()==b.length()){
            for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++){
                if(a.charAt(i)!=b.charAt(i))
                    diferentes++;
            }
        }
        else 
            diferentes=2;
        return diferentes;
    }

    public static boolean possibilidades(DirectedGraphList graph,String a,ArrayList<Integer> array){
        int diferentes=0;
        for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++){
            String numero=Integer.toString(array.get(i),6);
            diferentes=diferente(numero,a);
            if(diferentes==1){
                graph.addEdge(a,numero);
            }    
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    public void DFS(Vertice a){
        a.Visitado=true;
        for(int i=0;i<a.lst.size();i++){
            Vertice b=a.lst.get(i);
            if(!b.Visitado){
                DFS(b);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> numeros=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        criaArray(numeros,"/home/geovane/Documentos/CC/ALPROII/teste5000b");
        DirectedGraphList g = new DirectedGraphList();
        HeapSort.heapsort(numeros);
        for(int j=0;j<numeros.size();j++){
        g.addVertice(Integer.toString(numeros.get(j),6));
        }
        for(int i=0;i<numeros.size();i++){
            String numer=Integer.toString(numeros.get(i), 6);
            possibilidades(g,numer,numeros);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Você precisa exibir a sequência em si, ou achar o tamanho dela é suficiente pra você? Eu posso pular, por exemplo, de 15 para 10015 (sob a teoria de que 00015 e 10015 diferem em exatamente um dígito)?

Comment: Certo, esqueci de mencionar que todos os números tem que ter o mesmo numero de digitos, vou editar. Ou seja, não pode pular de 15 para 10015. Além disso, eu preciso printar a sequência.

Comment: Olá Geovane, [o problema do maior caminho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) é *NP-Hard*; a exceção são grafos acíclicos dirigidos; nesse caso é possível inverter os pesos (e.g, -1 por aresta) e usar um algoritmo de caminho mínimo.

Comment: Para fazer isso então eu teria que mudar a forma que faço minhas arestas, alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2):

Já que a gente não pode misturar números de tamanhos diferentes, o primeiro passo é separar a entrada em conjuntos contendo números de mesmo comprimento: no caso {31}, {154}, {3342, 1021, 2022, 2235, 4014, 3501, 3502, 4332, 1554, 3001}; a resposta necessariamente tem que ser igual à resposta de algum desses subconjuntos; eu vou usar pra ilustrar o algoritmo, não o seu exemplo, mas o conjunto {101, 322, 325, 342, 345, 422, 501, 502, 522} (em base 6, naturalmente).

[image: grafo de possíveis pares da sequência]

Eu listei os números já em ordem crescente pra tornar a primeira pergunta bem fácil: qual é a maior sequência que atende as condições do problema começando no 522? Obviamente é a sequência {522}, já que a restrição da sequência ser crescente garante que a gente não tem pra onde ir depois do 522.

A minha *segunda* pergunta: qual é a maior sequência começando no 502? Obviamente a resposta é {502, 522}, já que do {502} só dá pra ir pro {522}. Analogamente, é fácil ver que a maior sequência começando no 501 é {501, 502, 522}, etc.

Se você for analisando os números do exemplo em ordem decrescente, você não precisa pensar muito — você sempre vai ter zero ou uma alternativas — até chegar no 322.

[image: grafo parcial no nó 322]

(Os nós cinzas são nós que a gente já considerou; o número entre parênteses é o tamanho do maior caminho que começa naquele nó. O nó em vermelho — 322 é o nó que a gente está considerando agora.)

Agora a gente tem quatro possibilidades de continuar a sequência: {322, 522, …}, {322, 422, …}, {322, 342, …}, {322, 325, …}. Qual delas é maior? Ora, a gente sabe que, com exceção da sequência que começa em 522 (que só pode ter um termo), as outras escolhas permitem continuar por mais dois números. Logo a maior sequência que começa em 322 tem 1 + 2 = 3 termos.

Depois disso, é fácil ver que a maior (e única) sequência que começa em 101 tem 4 termos, e portanto é a solução do problema (pois se você olhar pra todos os nós do grafo, a maior sequência que começa em algum deles é 4).

---

Resumindo, a ideia do algoritmo é essa daqui:

```
para cada número n, em ordem decrescente:
    maior_sequência[n] := 1;  // sempre posso fazer a sequência unitária {n}
    para cada número “vizinho” v seguindo as regras do problema:
        // posso fazer a sequência {n, v, …}
        maior_sequência[n] := máximo(maior_sequência[n], 1 + maior_sequência[v]);        

retorne máximo(maior_sequência);
```

Faz sentido? Essa ideia funciona porque achar a maior sequência que começa em um dado número depende apenas do número: não importa *como* eu cheguei em *n* até agora; o caminho até *n* nunca afeta o caminho que eu posso seguir depois de *n*. Só é possível fazer isso porque o gráfico é *acíclico* — eu nunca posso voltar devido à restrição dos números serem crescentes.

Se eu **não** tivesse essa restrição, uma resposta válida para esse exemplo seria e.g. {101, 501, 502, 522, 422, 322, 342, 345, 325}, que passa por todos os números, mas esse problema é **muito** mais difícil, já que aí eu teria que de alguma forma guardar os números que eu já visitei. Neste exemplo, se eu não fizesse isso, eu poderia ter a sequência infinita, {**322**, 342, 345, 325, **322**, 342, 345, 325, **322**, …}.

Essa ideia é um exemplo de uma ideia muito mais geral chamada [programação dinâmica](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_din%C3%A2mica); o link da Wikipedia acho que confunde mais do que esclarece, mas eu não achei muito material em português. A [wiki da Maratona de Programação](http://wiki.maratona.dcc.ufmg.br/index.php/Roteiro_4) na UFMG tem mais problemas e algumas referências em inglês se você quiser estudar ideias parecidas.

Comment: (ficou clara a ideia do algoritmo? eu escrevi tudo num _stream of conciousness_; se alguma coisa não tiver ficado clara eu posso editar)

Comment: Esse algoritmo que tu postou, seria para adicionar em cada vértice o numero que está em parentesis ali no desenho do grafo, ou seja, o tamanho da sequencia que vem a seguir?

Comment: Isso — a sua classe `Vertice` teria que ter um campo a mais armazenando um inteiro (o tamanho da sequência que se segue). Se o seu programa precisar produzir uma _testemunha_ (um exemplo explícito de uma sequência válida), você também precisa ter um campo guardando uma referência pro próximo vértice da sequência (caso ocorra empate, qualquer vértice com o tamanho máximo serve; caso o vértice seja o último da sequência, você guarda `null` nesse campo); aí na saída você acha um vértice de início aceitável e vai avançando por esse campo pelo grafo.

Comment: Sim, eu preciso ter uma testemunha. Eu tentei implementar aqui o algoritmo que tu postou alí, mas os resultados não deram muito certo. Adicionei na classe vértice o atributo int.

`public void atribuiTamanhoSequencia(){
  for(int i=vert.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
   vert.get(i).maiorSequencia=1;
   for(int k=vert.get(i).lst.size();k>=0;k--){
    vert.get(i).maiorSequencia=Math.max(vert.get(i).maiorSequencia, vert.get(k).maiorSequencia+1);
   }
  }
 }`

Comment: Ah, desculpe, eu não sei ainda como botar código aqui nos comentários.

Comment: `vert.get(k)` (o k-ésimo vértice **do grafo**) não é o que você quer; você quer algo tipo `vert.get(i).lst.get(k)` (o k-ésimo **vértice vizinho a `i`**)

Comment: `public void atribuiTamanhoSequencia(){
  for(int i=vert.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
   vert.get(i).maiorSequencia=1;
   for(int k=vert.get(i).lst.size();k>=0;k--){
    vert.get(i).maiorSequencia=Math.max(vert.get(i).maiorSequencia, vert.get(i).lst.get(k).maiorSequencia+1);
   }
  }
  
 }`
Seria isso? Mas estou tendo IndexOutOfBounds

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24477/discussion-between-ctgpi-and-geovane-wickert).

Answer (score 1):

Só para atualizar e ajudar alguém que por um acaso queira o código resolvido.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class DirectedGraphList
{
private class Vertice
{
    private String item;
    private boolean Visitado;
    int maiorSequencia;
    Vertice proximo;
    private ArrayList<Vertice> lst = new ArrayList<Vertice>();

    public Vertice(String item) {
        this.item = item;
        Visitado=false;
        maiorSequencia=0;
        lst=new ArrayList<Vertice>();
        proximo=null;
    }
    public String getItem() {
        return this.item;
    }
    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
    public void addAdjacent(Vertice v) {
        if (!lst.contains(v))
            lst.add(v);
    }
    public ArrayList<Vertice> getAdjacents() {
        return lst;
    }
    public Vertice getAdjacent(int i) {
        Vertice res = null;
        if ((i >= 0) && (i < lst.size()))
            res = lst.get(i);
        return res;
    }
    public int getDegree(){
        return lst.size(); 
    }
}

private ArrayList<Vertice> vert;

public DirectedGraphList() {
    vert = new ArrayList<Vertice>();
}

private Vertice searchVerticeRef(String item)
{
    Vertice res = null;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; ((i < vert.size()) && !vert.get(i).getItem().equals(item)); i++);

    if (i < vert.size())
        res = vert.get(i);

    return res;
}

public void addVertice(String item)
{
    if (searchVerticeRef(item) == null) 
    {
        Vertice novo = new Vertice(item);
        vert.add(novo);
    }
}

public void addEdge(String strOrig, String strDest)
{
    Vertice vAux1 = searchVerticeRef(strOrig);
    Vertice vAux2 = searchVerticeRef(strDest);

    if (vAux1 == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Aresta origem invalida: " + strOrig);
    else if (vAux2 == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Aresta destino invalida: " + strDest);
    else
    {
        vAux1.addAdjacent(vAux2);
    }
}

public int getNumVertices() {
    return vert.size();
}

public int getDegree(String vertice)
{
    int i, j, c = 0;
    Vertice v = searchVerticeRef(vertice);
    if (v != null)
    {
        // grau de saida
        c += v.getDegree();

        // grau de entrada
        for (i = 0; i < vert.size(); i++)
        {
            if (!vert.get(i).getItem().equals(vertice))
            {
                for (j = 0; j < vert.get(i).getDegree(); j++)
                {
                    if (vert.get(i).getAdjacent(j).getItem().equals(vertice))
                        c++;
                }                   
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}

public ArrayList<String> getAllAdjacents(String vertice)
{
    ArrayList<String> res = null;
    Vertice v = searchVerticeRef(vertice);
    if (v != null)
    {
        res = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int j = 0; j < v.getDegree(); j++)
            res.add(v.getAdjacent(j).getItem());
    }
    return res;
}

public ArrayList<String> getSources()
{
    ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean checked;
    String vertice;

    for (int k=0; k<vert.size(); k++)
    {
        vertice = vert.get(k).getItem();

        checked = false;
        for (int i=0; i<vert.size(); i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<vert.get(i).getDegree(); j++)
            {
                if (vert.get(i).getAdjacent(j).getItem().equals(vertice))
                {
                    checked = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!checked)
            res.add(vertice);
    }
    return res;
}

public ArrayList<String> getSinks()
{
    ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i=0; i<vert.size(); i++)
    {
        if (vert.get(i).getAdjacents().isEmpty())
            res.add(vert.get(i).getItem());
    }
    return res;
}

public void showInfo()
{
    System.out.print("V = { ");
    for (int i = 0; i < vert.size()-1; i++)
        System.out.printf("%s, ", vert.get(i).getItem());
    System.out.printf("%s }\n", vert.get(vert.size()-1).getItem());

    ArrayList<String> arestas = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < vert.size(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < vert.get(i).lst.size(); j++)
            arestas.add(String.format("(%s, %s)", vert.get(i).getItem(), vert.get(i).getAdjacent(j).getItem()));

    System.out.print("E = {\n");
    if (!arestas.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.printf("      %s", arestas.get(0));

        for (int i = 1; i < arestas.size(); i++)
            System.out.printf(",\n      %s", arestas.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println("\n    }");
}
public static void criaArray(ArrayList<Integer> a,String nome) throws FileNotFoundException{
    try{
        FileReader ler= new FileReader(nome);
        BufferedReader arq=new BufferedReader(ler);
        int parsedStr;
        String str=arq.readLine();
        while(str!=null){
            parsedStr=Integer.parseInt(str);
            a.add(parsedStr);
            str=arq.readLine();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Erro na abertura do arquivo: "+
                e.getMessage());
    }
}
public static int diferente(String a,String b){
    int diferentes=0;
    if(a.length()==b.length()){
        for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++){
            if(a.charAt(i)!=b.charAt(i))
                diferentes++;
        }
    }
    else 
        diferentes=2;
    return diferentes;
}
public static boolean maior(String str1,String str2){
    int aux=Integer.parseInt(str1, 6);
    int aux1=Integer.parseInt(str2, 6);
    if(aux>aux1)
        return true;
    else return false;
}

public static boolean possibilidades(DirectedGraphList graph,String a,ArrayList<Integer> array){
    int diferentes=0;
    for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++){
        String numero=Integer.toString(array.get(i),6);
        diferentes=diferente(numero,a);
        if(diferentes==1 && maior(numero,a)){
            graph.addEdge(a,numero);
        }   
    }
    return true;
}

public void printaSequencia(Vertice a){
    System.out.println(a.item);
    Vertice atual=a;
    while(atual.proximo!=null){
        atual=atual.proximo;
        System.out.println(atual.item);
    }
}

public void atribuiTamanhoSequencia(){
    for(int i=vert.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
        vert.get(i).maiorSequencia=1;
        for(int k=vert.get(i).lst.size()-1;k>=0;k--){
            if (vert.get(i).lst.get(k).maiorSequencia+1 > vert.get(i).maiorSequencia){
                vert.get(i).maiorSequencia=vert.get(i).lst.get(k).maiorSequencia+1;
                vert.get(i).proximo=vert.get(i).lst.get(k);
            }
        }
    }

}
public Vertice getVerticeInicial(){
    Vertice aux=null;
    int tamanho=0;
    for(int i=0;i<vert.size();i++){
        if(vert.get(i).maiorSequencia>tamanho){
            aux=vert.get(i);
            tamanho=vert.get(i).maiorSequencia;
        }
    }
    return aux;
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    ArrayList<Integer> numeros=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    criaArray(numeros,"/home/geovane/Documentos/CC/ALPROII/test100000a");
    DirectedGraphList g = new DirectedGraphList();
    HeapSort.heapsort(numeros);
    for(int j=0;j<numeros.size();j++){
    g.addVertice(Integer.toString(numeros.get(j),6));
    }
    for(int i=0;i<numeros.size();i++){
        String numer=Integer.toString(numeros.get(i), 6);
        possibilidades(g,numer,numeros);
    }
    g.atribuiTamanhoSequencia();
    Vertice inicial=g.getVerticeInicial();
    g.printaSequencia(inicial);
}
}
```

Problema resolvido!! Obrigado @ctgPi